# Celery Chain - The final task is never called

Tags: celery, celery-task

The sequence chain(group(tasks), final_sum.s()) does not provide arguments for the second task
final_sum.s() in outer chain doesn't get executed even though everything else succeeds.

```
def function_task():
tasks1 = []
for i in xrange(10, 13):
    tasks.append(add.s(i))
the_big_task1 = chain(get_one.s(), group(tasks1), sum_fun.s())
tasks2 = []
for i in xrange(20, 23):
    tasks2.append(add.s(i))
the_big_task2 = chain(get_one.s(), group(tasks2), sum_fun.s())

chain(group([the_big_task1, the_big_task2]), final_sum.s())()

@celery_app.task(name='tasks.get_one')
def get_one():
    return 1


@celery_app.task(name='tasks.add')
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@celery_app.task(name='tasks.sum_fun')
def sum_fun(a_list):
    return sum(a_list)

@celery_app.task(name='tasks.final_sum')
def final_sum(header_results): 
    # do something
```

The problem we are having is that the final task is never called.
We have also tried wrapping it in a chord, which doesn’t work either.

Python version - 2.7
Celery version - 3.1.25

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
chain(group([the_big_task1, the_big_task2]))(final_sum.s())
```

Output of `group([the_big_task1, the_big_task2])` will be the args of `final_sum`.

The way you wrote the flow, it's supposed to work, that's strange, `chord` didn't work either.